# Custom headers with pycurl 

Tags: python, header, pycurl

Can I send a *custom header* like "yaddayadda" to the server with the [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) request?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I would code something like:

```
pycurl_connect = pycurl.Curl()
pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.URL, your_url)
pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['header_name1: header_value1',
                                          'header_name2: header_value2'])
pycurl_connect.perform()
```

Comment: how about multiple headers? Like a list?

Comment: why a pseudo-dictionary instead of a real dictionary? ['key: val', 'key: val'] vs {'key': 'val', 'key': 'val'}...

Answer (score 6):

you can, with HTTPHEADER. just provide your custom headers as a list, like so:

`header = ['test: yadayadayada', 'blahblahblah']`

`curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, header)`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use human_curl library https://github.com/Lispython/human_curl

```
custom_headers = (
('Test-Header', 'fwkjenwkljbnfkjqnewfrjven3lrf'),
('Another-Header', 'ifenwqnfe;wnfqfjlweqnnlf')
)

r = human_curl.get("http://stackoverflow.com",
                    headers=custom_headers)
```

Comment: This does not seem to support Python 3