# Limiting the text download content in pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

I want to download site content using curl in python (pycurl). But I don't want the whole text of those sites just some part of the site. I want to reduce my time taken in downloading the whole text. Thankyou.

Comment: That's not how web requests work. You ask for a page, you get the page.

Comment: @Amber no, that's not how they work.

Comment: @Kimvais in a general sense, yes, it is. There is some support for downloading certain byte offsets of files, but that's very rarely useful for selecting specific *text* - it's designed for breaking up downloads of files into chunks and/or resuming interrupted downloads.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the [relevant](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/http/draft-fielding-http/p5-range.html#header.range) [headers](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/http/draft-fielding-http/p5-range.html#header.if-range) in your HTTP request, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044782/custom-headers-with-pycurl) on how to do it with `pycurl`

**NOTE**: This *only* works if you:

1. Know the data offset (in bytes) where in the result the data you want is
2. The web server supports this

Answer (score 0):

The delay in loading a page, generally, is not in the actual download of the HTML -- that's often quite quick as html is nothing more than Unicode text. Unless there is a *HUGE* amount of actual text and markup on a page you're not going to save much. Further, in order to get any of the actual content of the page, you'll need to download the entire `<head>` anyway...

Personally, I would approach this asynchronously. [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is one of the more common suggestions for this type of approach.